# Let $a=2e_1+3e_2-4e_3$ and $b=e_1-e_2+3e_3$. find $a \land b$. Determine the area of the parallelogram formed by $a\land b$

Tags: linear-algebra

$(e_1+3e_2-4e_3)$ $\land$ $(e_1-e_2+3e_3)$ = $2e_1 \land e_1$ - $2e_1 \land e_2$ + $6e_1 \land e_3$ + $3e_2 \land e_1$ - $3e_2 \land e_2$ +$9e_2 \land e_3$ - $4e_3 \land e_1$ + $4e_3 \land e_2$ - $12e_3 \land e_3$ = - $2e_1 \land e_2$ + $6e_1 \land e_3$ - $3e_1 \land e_2$ + $9e_2 \land e_3$ +$4e_1 \land e_3$ - $4e_2 \land e_3$ = -$5e_1 \land e_2$ + $10e_1 \land e_3$ + $5e_2 \land e_3$. After I found $a \land b$, I am lost on finding the area of the parallelogram formed by $a \land b$.

Answer (score 1):

the area is $|a\land b|=|-5e_1 \land e_2 + 10e_1 \land e_3 + 5e_2 \land e_3|=\sqrt{(-5)^2 + 10^2 + 5^2}=5\sqrt{6}$

Comment: wow so a regular magnitude equation solve this?

Comment: yeah, it's the same as **cross product**.
see https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cross_product